# Stop GSAP function after it runs

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gsap

I'm very new to the concept of web animations.

I'm right now developing "Windows Hello animation".

[**IN THIS CODE EXAMPLE**](https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/bGpKVGp) -
HOW DO I STOP THE ANIMATION AFTER 1st Run, and trigger another JS function afterward.

I've tried many things but couldn't get it to work.

Please help me with where should I change the code.

**CODE-**

JS

```js
var mainCtr = $("#main-ctr"),
    hello = $(".hello"),
    eyeLeft = $("#eye-left"),
    eyeRight = $("#eye-right"),
    eyeToLeft = $("#eye-to-left"),
    eyeToRight = $("#eye-to-right"),
    wink = $("#wink"),
    smileUp = $("#smile-up"),
    smileDown = $("#smile-down"),
    smile = $("#smile");

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: -1,
  repeatDelay: .3,
  delay: .3
});

TweenMax.set([mainCtr, hello], {
  opacity: 0
});

tl
  .to(mainCtr, .3, {
    opacity: 1
  })
  .to(smileDown, .3, {
    morphSVG: "#smile-up"
  })
  .to(smile, .3, {
    rotation: -30,
    transformOrigin: "center center",
    ease: Circ.ease
  })
  .to(smile, .9, {
    rotation: 900,
    transformOrigin: "center center",
    ease: Circ.easeInOut
  })
  .to(eyeLeft, .3, {
    morphSVG: "#eye-to-left",
    ease: Power2.ease
  }, "-=.3")
  .to(eyeRight, .3, {
    morphSVG: "#eye-to-right",
    ease: Power2.ease
  }, "-=.3")
  .to(eyeRight, .1, {
    scaleY: .25,
    transformOrigin: "center center"
  })
  .to(eyeRight, .1, {
    scaleY: 1
  })
  .to(hello, .3, {
    opacity: 1
  }, "-=.3")
  .to(mainCtr, .6, {
    delay: 1,
    opacity: 0
  })
```

[**YOU CAN SEE THE CODE LIVE HERE**](https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/bGpKVGp)

Comment: We highly recommend that you upgrade to [GSAP 3 formatting](https://greensock.com/3-migration/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, acheive this by simply removing the `repeat` and `repeatDelay` from the TimelineMax function options and to fire a callback once the animation is complete you can use the `onComplete` option in the TimelineMax function like below:

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({
  delay: .3,
  onComplete: function(){
   alert('hello')
  }
});
```

Comment: This Cheat Sheet for GSAP may also come in handy: https://greensock.com/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 1):

I updated your codepen with what you are looking for: [here](https://codepen.io/ale917k/pen/oNxyjLO)

```
var mainCtr = $("#main-ctr"),
    hello = $(".hello"),
    eyeLeft = $("#eye-left"),
    eyeRight = $("#eye-right"),
    eyeToLeft = $("#eye-to-left"),
    eyeToRight = $("#eye-to-right"),
    wink = $("#wink"),
    smileUp = $("#smile-up"),
    smileDown = $("#smile-down"),
    smile = $("#smile");

var tl = new TimelineMax();

TweenMax.set([mainCtr, hello], {
  opacity: 0
});

tl
  .to(mainCtr, .3, {
    opacity: 1
  })
  .to(smileDown, .3, {
    morphSVG: "#smile-up"
  })
  .to(smile, .3, {
    rotation: -30,
    transformOrigin: "center center",
    ease: Circ.ease
  })
  .to(smile, .9, {
    rotation: 900,
    transformOrigin: "center center",
    ease: Circ.easeInOut
  })
  .to(eyeLeft, .3, {
    morphSVG: "#eye-to-left",
    ease: Power2.ease
  }, "-=.3")
  .to(eyeRight, .3, {
    morphSVG: "#eye-to-right",
    ease: Power2.ease
  }, "-=.3")
  .to(eyeRight, .1, {
    scaleY: .25,
    transformOrigin: "center center"
  })
  .to(eyeRight, .1, {
    scaleY: 1
  })
  .to(hello, .3, {
    opacity: 1
  }, "-=.3")
```

You only needed to remove the repeat attribute when you set up your timeline at line 12 (if you set repeat: -1, it means it will be an infinite loop).

To notice I updated the last line as well, so the smile stays there. If you want it to disappear instead, then you just need to add back this bit of code at the end of your js file:

```
.to(mainCtr, .6, {
  delay: 1,
  opacity: 0
})
```